# I have provided Install execute sequence of the action as After="InstallInitialize",however it is running at uninstall.How can I prevent it?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, custom-action

I want to execute a custom action in wix toolset before installation begins.I am trying to maintain migrations during an update.So if before installation there is already an install folder I want to copy my existing database to some other location.I have provided the Install execute sequence as After="InstallInitialize".However, my custom action is executed on uninstall.When I install for the first time nothing happens because there was no install folder,so this is the right behavior.But my problem is when I uninstall the application the database is getting copied to a temporary location.How can I prevent it from running at uninstall?

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition for.your custom action (in the InstallExecuteSequence table) of: 
    NOT REMOVE~=ALL

Comment: You need to post some examples and show the community what you have done....the condition above should work fine.

Comment: After your comment I tried it again and it worked.Thank you so much. The problem was with the execute sequence, earlier I scheduled it after install initialize and it was not working.Now I have scheduled it after install finalize and it is working.

Comment: You're welcome.  As a heads up, Custom Actions scheduled before InstallInitialize or after InstallFinalize should be 'immediate'.  Custom Actions scheduled between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize should be 'deferred'.